# Two LIKE conditions in one SQL query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I have a datagridview and I want to set it user to search data using textbox.
I am using vb.net and MS Access.

Here is my SQL code. When I run it, there is an error

> no value given for one or more parameter

Code:

```
("select * from itemtbl where (item_id like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%') or (item_desc like '%" & TextBox1.Text & "%') ", objcon1.mydataconnection)
```

Comment: Does it happen no matter the text or only for specific text?

Comment: You should consider providing a [mcve]. Also use SQL parameters. Don't concatenate strings like that.

Comment: " Does it happen no matter the text or only for specific text?"   there is no specific text .its working use 1 condition.but i want to user serch id or name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the wildcard sign of Access, a *star*:

```
("select * from itemtbl where (item_id like '*" & TextBox1.Text & "*') or (item_desc like '*" & TextBox1.Text & "*') ", objcon1.mydataconnection)
```

Comment: Then probably one or more of you field names are misspelled. That's typical for this error.

Comment: * is not worked for me.but problem is missspeld in table row.thank you for your help